# Сделать выделение рамки на изображении, Android

Tags: java, android

У меня задача: есть некое изображение, на котором надо выделить прямоугольную рамку и на выходе получить координаты левой верхней и правой нижней ее точек. Я собраюсь это делать в новом `Activity`, которое, собственно ,на результате вернет две координаты. Но я просто не представляю, с чего мне начать.

Можете посоветовать какие-нибудь библиотеки, или подсказать как лучше реализовать это?

Comment: вы хотите обозначить какую то часть изображения что ли,  что то [вроде кропа](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)?

Comment: @pavlofff библиотека отличная, сейчас протестить нет возможности, но судя по вики - там выделенная область сохраняется в в новое изображение, а мне надо именно получить координаты выделения. Ну, все равно, большое спасибо, в крайнем случае использую исходники этой библиотеки.